# inserting multiple value in one column in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my sql query

```
update employee 
set StaticIp='(59.90.187.91),( 117.218.1.147)'
where EmpId=1001
```

Error msg:Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the value you want to save in that column will not fit and will be truncated.

There is no way around this except if you increase the size of the column.

You can see the size of your column by running:

```
sp_columns @table_name = 'employee', @column_name = 'StaticIp'
```

In order to change the size of your column you need to run this command:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ALTER COLUMN StaticIp NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Comment: What is the sytax to upadte table with multiple value in one column@Radu Gheorghiu @Terror.Blade

Comment: @son Your syntax is right You need to update length of StaticIp column, Post the structure of employee table.

Answer (score 0):

This message occures when you try to insert the length data more than the database column size
run the following query.

```
sp_help employee
```

check the length of staticip column , it must be less than you are entering.

Answer (score 0):

Storing Comma separated values in a column is bad practice.

You're getting this error of String or binary data would be truncated because StaticIP column's length is less than what you're trying to update with.

Resolution: Increase the length of StaticIP column. like `StaticIP nvarchar(255)`

Comment: but it is taking (59.90.187.91),( 117.218.1.147) as one value but i need to check for individual ip address for eachrecord